# RAID 5 reshape halted after hardware failure, tried to add disk again but, now it is added as spare

Tags: centos, mdadm, raid5

I have a 4 disk RAID5 (at a system with centos7).
Space was all used up, so decided to add another disk and grow the array.
So purchased a SATA card, added it to the machine and added disk on it.
Then I added the disk in raid array, it added as spare.
I made it active, and applied for grow by +1.
But the SATA card failed and disk got removed during reshape.
I removed SATA card and added the same new disk with sata cable from DVD ROM.
I again added the disk into array.
but now the new disk status is spare,
and the reshape is stuck at around 4kb/sec.

my question is, at this state, how can I revert back quickly to the original 4 disk raid5?
or make my disk sdf as active to replace the removed disk?

/proc/mdstat result

```
    [root@jpnsrv ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdf[8](S) sdb[7] sdd[4] sdc[5] sde[6]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/4] [UUUU_]
      [>....................]  reshape =  0.6% (11748448/1953382400) finish=7778242.6min speed=4K/sec
      bitmap: 1/15 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

details of array:

```
 [root@jpnsrv ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Aug  1 18:16:31 2015
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jun 27 18:10:18 2020
             State : clean, degraded, reshaping
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Reshape Status : 0% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (4->5)

              Name : jpnsrv.net:0  (local to host jpnsrv.net)
              UUID : eaec44b2:6bae23a2:264d4e51:8199a8db
            Events : 142776

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       5       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       4       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
       7       8       16        2      active sync   /dev/sdb
       6       8       64        3      active sync   /dev/sde
       -       0        0        4      removed

       8       8       80        -      spare   /dev/sdf
```

Please help, I don't want to lose data... also make data accessible as quickly as possible.

Comment: The way to not lose data is to keep current backups. RAID is no replacement for backup. If you don't have a backup, make one now, before doing anything else with your already fragilized RAID.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.
We attempted recovery with UFS explorer, but XFS file system already broken.
So we could recover only the level2 and below folders as it is.
We applied for data recovery company, they also got same results.
We got our data back.

Thank you all.